# Network password rejected after installing backport-iwlwifi-dkms

Tags: networking, lenovo, 19.10, iwlwifi

Fresh install of Kubuntu 19.10 on a new Lenovo P53.

At first the Wifi network works, and I'm able to connect to my home Wifi using the usual password.

The driver manager recommends to install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`, which I do, but now the passwords are rejected. I also tried my phone hotspot (that has a rather simple password) and it is rejected too. I can connect to the phone hotspot if I reconfigure it to be password-less.

Password can be displayed and is OK, I even copy/pasted it.

The log of a connection sequence from /var/log/syslog (it seems it tried first to connect using a stored password which is very likely the right one too):

```
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9624] device (wlp82s0): Activation: starting connection 'HomeNetwork' (9ca67590-8a02-495c-a7cb-da56076aad08)
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9627] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="9ca67590-8a02-495c-a7cb-da56076aad08" name="HomeNetwork" pid=1633 uid=1000 result="success"
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 kernel: [ 2997.428660] wlp82s0: authenticate with 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 (SSID='HomeNetwork' freq=5260 MHz)
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9630] device (wlp82s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9643] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9656] device (wlp82s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9664] device (wlp82s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HomeNetwork' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9665] device (wlp82s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9684] device (wlp82s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9687] device (wlp82s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9688] device (wlp82s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HomeNetwork' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9688] Config: added 'ssid' value 'HomeNetwork'
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9688] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9688] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9688] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9689] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9793] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293941.9793] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Jan 17 21:45:41 P53 kernel: [ 2997.433797] wlp82s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 (try 1/3)
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: Trying to associate with 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 (SSID='HomeNetwork' freq=5260 MHz)
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293942.0044] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293942.0044] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2997.458775] wlp82s0: authenticated
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2997.461167] wlp82s0: associate with 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 (try 1/3)
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2997.463098] wlp82s0: RX AssocResp from 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=4)
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: Associated with 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2997.468796] wlp82s0: associated
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293942.0195] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293942.0195] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2997.523928] wlp82s0: Limiting TX power to 17 (20 - 3) dBm as advertised by 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68
Jan 17 21:45:42 P53 kernel: [ 2998.015706] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 kernel: [ 2998.480972] wlp82s0: deauthenticating from 14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: WPA: Failed to set PTK to the driver (alg=3 keylen=16 bssid=14:0c:76:bc:ab:68)
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=14:0c:76:bc:ab:68 reason=1 locally_generated=1
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HomeNetwork" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HomeNetwork" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/3
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <warn>  [1579293943.0361] sup-iface[0x55e11c9c6be0,wlp82s0]: connection disconnected (reason -1)
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.0412] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.0420] device (wlp82s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.0420] device (wlp82s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.0424] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.1413] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 17 21:45:43 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293943.1413] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0258] device (wlp82s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0262] device (wlp82s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0265] device (wlp82s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HomeNetwork' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0265] Config: added 'ssid' value 'HomeNetwork'
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0265] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0265] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0265] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0266] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0372] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan 17 21:45:54 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293954.0372] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 (SSID='HomeNetwork' freq=2447 MHz)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.490277] wlp82s0: authenticate with 14:0c:76:55:47:d1
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0417] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0417] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.496321] wlp82s0: send auth to 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 (try 1/3)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: Trying to associate with 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 (SSID='HomeNetwork' freq=2447 MHz)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.520689] wlp82s0: authenticated
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.521092] wlp82s0: associate with 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 (try 1/3)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0662] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0662] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.525437] wlp82s0: RX AssocResp from 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: Associated with 14:0c:76:55:47:d1
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.531546] wlp82s0: associated
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0822] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.0822] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: WPA: Failed to set PTK to the driver (alg=3 keylen=16 bssid=14:0c:76:55:47:d1)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 kernel: [ 3010.543158] wlp82s0: deauthenticating from 14:0c:76:55:47:d1 by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=14:0c:76:55:47:d1 reason=1 locally_generated=1
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HomeNetwork" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HomeNetwork" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 wpa_supplicant[1122]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/3
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <warn>  [1579293955.1000] sup-iface[0x55e11c9c6be0,wlp82s0]: connection disconnected (reason -1)
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.1051] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.1056] device (wlp82s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.1057] device (wlp82s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.1060] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.2052] device (wlp82s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 17 21:45:55 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293955.2052] device (p2p-dev-wlp82s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jan 17 21:45:57 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <warn>  [1579293957.0813] device (wlp82s0): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
Jan 17 21:45:57 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293957.0814] device (wlp82s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 21:45:57 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293957.0817] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 17 21:45:57 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <warn>  [1579293957.0824] device (wlp82s0): Activation: failed for connection 'HomeNetwork'
Jan 17 21:45:57 P53 NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1579293957.0826] device (wlp82s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

The part of `lshw` that seems relevant:

```
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 memory:ce200000-ce2fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: Intel Corporation
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
                logical name: wlp82s0
                version: 1a
                serial: 94:e6:f7:f4:70:cc
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
                resources: irq:17 memory:ce200000-ce203fff
```

Any ideas?

Otherwise how do I reinstall the previous one?

```
$$>dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`, and I'll give you the command to remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Just waiting to see if there is a less radical solution. Your answer will be much appreciated otherwise.

Comment: Real simple. Wifi worked. You installed a driver. Wifi broke. Theoretically you can uninstall the driver, fix the wifi... and later, if you desire to reinstall the driver, you can. Your question **was** *"how do I reinstall the previous one? "*.

Comment: Could be  a firmware mismatch, or there is a further version of the driver...

Comment: In less than 30 seconds you can find out...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Eventually uninstalled, but that doesn't answer the main question.  I didn't install a random driver, I installed a driver recommended y the software manager, from Ubuntu repos. And this driver is backported from a version I'll soon upgrade to, so upgrading could break the Wifi support, and I won't have the possibility to uninstall the driver. So I want to know the root cause. Driver bug? Bad/mismatched firmware?

Comment: I had a case just like this a few weeks ago. The solution was also to uninstall this driver. I don't know EXACTLY what problem, or circumstance, that this backport driver is required, but apparently it's not standard 19.10. Maybe with a specific kernel.

Comment: My recent learning indicates that the backport driver is not for kernels 5.0.0 or higher. 19.10 has 5.3.x.

Comment: Please add this to you answer (with due references) so that I can accept it.

Comment: I've added the note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wifi worked. You installed a new driver. Wifi broke.

*How do I reinstall the previous one (driver)?*

```
dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

To remove the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` driver, and revert to the original `iwlwifi` driver...

`sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/7906 -k 5.3.0-26-generic`

`reboot`

**Note**: [As per this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205996/iwlwifi-causing-system-hangs-on-ubuntu-19-10) the backport-iwlwifi-dkms cannot be used with kernels 5.0.0+