# iwlwifi causing system hangs on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: crash, 19.10, iwlwifi

I have a Dell Inspiron 7580 laptop and I've been using Ubuntu 19.10 for a while. In the last few weeks, I've been experiencing frequent hangs, making the OS unresponsive for 20-30 seconds. The output of syslog usually shows the following information:

```
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.019296] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.019299] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 175 write_ptr 176
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 anacron[953]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 anacron[953]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 anacron[6018]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-01-26
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 anacron[6018]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.268042] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
Jan 26 22:33:41 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.268043] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275389] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275391] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: -471993682
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275392] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275393] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x47212682 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275394] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xB3F69877 | trm_hw_status0
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275395] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x98C2A8C2 | trm_hw_status1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275395] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD5AB7FA3 | branchlink2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275396] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x118A1E62 | interruptlink1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275397] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x27EBD5F7 | interruptlink2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275397] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x635421A5 | data1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275398] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x39C800D6 | data2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275399] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9102E5A5 | data3
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275399] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD038E2FF | beacon time
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275400] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0EF4CD60 | tsf low
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275401] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7FFFE3FE | tsf hi
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275401] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0004620C | time gp1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275402] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA3BED9AF | time gp2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275403] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0251201B | uCode revision type
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275403] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x05FF74EA | uCode version major
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275404] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7B631323 | uCode version minor
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275405] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7A7AD76D | hw version
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275405] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7036CAB2 | board version
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275406] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00052BDE | hcmd
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275406] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF7FC7B9F | isr0
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275407] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9A040E40 | isr1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275408] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFE7FBEF3 | isr2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275408] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5B48F682 | isr3
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275409] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9B5FDECD | isr4
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275410] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x910E6195 | last cmd Id
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275410] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x368CBB26 | wait_event
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275411] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x1EB42170 | l2p_control
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275412] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5F134C3F | l2p_duration
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275412] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4B2B101B | l2p_mhvalid
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275413] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x63E0CB7F | l2p_addr_match
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275414] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA8ED5A66 | lmpm_pmg_sel
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275414] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xDBF3CBE7 | timestamp
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275415] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x15D5E4A1 | flow_handler
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275580] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275581] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 1180119579
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275581] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xEF86B563 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275582] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x315DDDCA | umac branchlink1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275583] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xB5333377 | umac branchlink2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275583] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x303CD2A6 | umac interruptlink1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275584] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xE9F78AD7 | umac interruptlink2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275585] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20050572 | umac data1
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275585] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF662DC7D | umac data2
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275586] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD792349E | umac data3
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275587] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x97D5D3DF | umac major
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275587] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9CB36342 | umac minor
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275588] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5EFFBFB6 | frame pointer
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275589] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x194111F1 | stack pointer
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275589] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x6EB773FC | last host cmd
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275590] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0335B0AD | isr status reg
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275731] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275800] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.275934] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276068] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276202] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276336] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276470] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276605] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276739] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.276874] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.277007] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.277142] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.277275] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.277279] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
Jan 26 22:33:43 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  305.277282] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430644] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 22s! [kworker/4:3:1080]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430646] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac bnep uvcvideo btusb btrtl btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc btintel videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc ecdh_generic ecc snd_hda_codec_hdmi nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nvidia_uvm(OE) sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda coretemp snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_skl nvidia_drm(POE) snd_soc_hdac_hda kvm_intel snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc kvm joydev nvidia_modeset(POE) snd_soc_sst_dsp irqbypass snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nvidia(POE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep crct10dif_pclmul snd_pcm crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi iwlmvm snd_seq mac80211 dell_laptop ledtrig_audio snd_seq_device aesni_intel mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr libarc4 dell_smm_hwmon snd_timer
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430666]  i915 aes_x86_64 crypto_simd dell_wmi dell_smbios cryptd dcdbas glue_helper intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf drm_kms_helper iwlwifi drm snd processor_thermal_device ipmi_devintf i2c_algo_bit ipmi_msghandler input_leds intel_rapl_common fb_sys_fops syscopyarea serio_raw sysfillrect mei_me dell_wmi_descriptor hid_multitouch soundcore cfg80211 ucsi_acpi wmi_bmof idma64 typec_ucsi intel_pch_thermal mei intel_soc_dts_iosf virt_dma sysimgblt mac_hid mxm_wmi typec int3403_thermal intel_hid int3400_thermal int3402_thermal acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone sparse_keymap acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 usbhid hid_generic nvme psmouse nvme_core r8169 i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci ahci intel_lpss realtek libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_cannonlake wmi video pinctrl_intel
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430683] CPU: 4 PID: 1080 Comm: kworker/4:3 Tainted: P           OE     5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430684] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7580/0W83FH, BIOS 1.9.0 08/26/2019
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430693] Workqueue: events iwl_fw_error_dump_wk [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430697] RIP: 0010:_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x15/0x20
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430698] Code: 00 e9 78 ff ff ff 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 c6 07 00 0f 1f 40 00 48 89 f7 57 9d <0f> 1f 44 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 40 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 49 89 f8 b8 00
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430699] RSP: 0018:ffffb2f240cd7cb8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430700] RAX: ffffffffc0788480 RBX: ffff9429a62b0018 RCX: 0000000000000003
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430700] RDX: 0000000008040005 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430700] RBP: ffffb2f240cd7cb8 R08: 0000000000003a98 R09: 0000000000000011
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430701] R10: ffffe9590e461048 R11: 00000000000049c3 R12: 00000000fffffff7
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430701] R13: ffffb2f240cd7cf0 R14: 0000000000400000 R15: ffff9429aa54acb8
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430702] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9429af500000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430702] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430703] CR2: 00005597a7218da4 CR3: 00000004634fe005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430703] Call Trace:
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430709]  iwl_trans_pcie_release_nic_access+0x61/0x70 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430712]  iwl_trans_pcie_read_mem+0x94/0xc0 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430716]  iwl_fw_dump_mem.isra.0.part.0+0x50/0x90 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430720]  iwl_fw_error_dump_file.isra.0+0x436/0xf80 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430724]  iwl_fw_dbg_collect_sync+0x35c/0x910 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430725]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430727]  ? __switch_to+0x7f/0x470
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430728]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430731]  iwl_fw_error_dump_wk+0x59/0x80 [iwlwifi]
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430732]  process_one_work+0x1db/0x380
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430733]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430735]  kthread+0x104/0x140
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430736]  ? process_one_work+0x380/0x380
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430737]  ? kthread_park+0x80/0x80
Jan 26 22:34:09 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.430737]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[2343]: Starting Notification regarding a crash report...
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 update-notifier-crash[6039]: /usr/bin/whoopsie
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1118]: Starting Notification regarding a crash report...
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 update-notifier-crash[6044]: /usr/bin/whoopsie
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.932667] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  333.953178] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 update-notifier-crash[6039]: /var/crash/linux-image-5
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 update-notifier-crash[6044]: /var/crash/linux-image-5
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1118]: update-notifier-crash.service: Succeeded.
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 systemd[1118]: Started Notification regarding a crash report.
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  334.067892] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  334.143142] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [  334.164255] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 wpa_supplicant[947]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
Jan 26 22:34:10 tiago-Inspiron-7580 NetworkManager[1007]: <info>  [1580088850.6519] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

I've even tried to perform a clean installation of Ubuntu this weekend, but the crashes are still happening. I'm using `tlp`, but I don't think that's causing the issue.

I'm on kernel version `5.3.0-26-generic`. Is this a known issue in the latest kernel version? Any workarounds?

Thanks for the help

## Edit 1

The output of `dkms status` is the following:

```
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

The **Additional Drivers** window in Ubuntu shows the following information:

```
- NVIDIA Corporation: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
-- The device is using the recommended driver.
--- (*) Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-435 (proprietary, tested)

- Intel Corporation: Wireless-AC 9260
-- This device is not working.
--- ( ) Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format from backport-iwlwifi-dkms (open source)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7GfA.jpg

The information above has always been this way. But my wifi seems to be working properly and I wasn't experiencing system hangs a few weeks ago.

## Edit 2

As instructed, I've installed `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. The installation output was the following:

```
Loading new backport-iwlwifi-7906 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-26-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-26-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

compat.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

iwlwifi.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

iwlxvt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

iwlmvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

mac80211.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

cfg80211.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Module has been obsoleted due to being included
in kernel 5.0.0.  We will avoid installing
for future kernels above 5.0.0.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
```

Running `dkms status` now shows the following:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 435.21, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

## Edit 3

The output of `ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms` is:

```
total 28988
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 jan 29 06:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 jan 29 06:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    74453 jan 29 06:16 nvidia-drm.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26597357 jan 29 06:16 nvidia.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1473197 jan 29 06:16 nvidia-modeset.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1522405 jan 29 06:16 nvidia-uvm.ko
```

## Edit 4

I've now removed the package `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` using the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

## Edit 5

I've also upgraded the kernel to the latest version using:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I'm now on kernel `5.3.0-29-generic`.

I haven't had crashes in the last few days. So maybe that helped.

## Edit 6

I've just has the crash twice. Here's the output of `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 10 16:39:00 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1352.793741] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Queue 0 is active on fifo 7 and stuck for 2500 ms. SW [60, 61] HW [61, 61] FH TRB=0x070003c
Feb 10 16:39:02 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.033960] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms.
Feb 10 16:39:02 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.033963] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Current CMD queue read_ptr 60 write_ptr 62
Feb 10 16:39:02 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.282794] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
Feb 10 16:39:02 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.282794] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290328] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290331] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: -471862610
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290332] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x47012682 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF3E69877 | trm_hw_status0
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9CC2E8C2 | trm_hw_status1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290336] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x97AB7F83 | branchlink2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290336] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x018A1E62 | interruptlink1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290337] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x27EBD5F6 | interruptlink2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290338] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x634421A5 | data1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290338] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x3DC84056 | data2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290339] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9912E591 | data3
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290340] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD038EAFF | beacon time
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290340] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x02F4CD60 | tsf low
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290341] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7FFFE3FE | tsf hi
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290342] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0004620C | time gp1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290342] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xB39CD9AE | time gp2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290343] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x02512013 | uCode revision type
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x05FF7D8A | uCode version major
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x3B639322 | uCode version minor
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290345] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7A76976D | hw version
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290346] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x7836DAB2 | board version
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290346] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00852BCE | hcmd
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290347] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF7FC7D97 | isr0
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290348] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9A040E40 | isr1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290348] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFE7FBEF3 | isr2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290349] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5A48F682 | isr3
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290349] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9B57DEC5 | isr4
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290350] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x910EE191 | last cmd Id
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290351] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x368CBBAE | wait_event
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290351] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0FFE2170 | l2p_control
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290352] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4F134C7F | l2p_duration
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290353] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x4B2A101B | l2p_mhvalid
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290353] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x62E0DB37 | l2p_addr_match
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290354] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x29FD5A66 | lmpm_pmg_sel
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290355] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xDBF3CBE7 | timestamp
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290355] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x15D5E4A5 | flow_handler
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290523] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 1180135963
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA787F563 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290525] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x315DCDCA | umac branchlink1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290526] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xB5333375 | umac branchlink2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290526] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x303CD2A6 | umac interruptlink1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290527] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xE9F78AF5 | umac interruptlink2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290528] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20050572 | umac data1
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290528] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xF662DE7D | umac data2
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290529] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xD3123C9E | umac data3
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290530] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x97D5D3DF | umac major
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290530] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x9CB36362 | umac minor
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290531] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x5EFFBBD7 | frame pointer
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290531] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x194119B1 | stack pointer
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290532] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x6EB76BFC | last host cmd
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290533] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0335F0AD | isr status reg
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290675] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290743] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.290877] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291011] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291145] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291279] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291413] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291547] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291681] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291815] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.291949] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.292083] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.292217] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.292221] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
Feb 10 16:39:04 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1355.292224] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
Feb 10 16:39:30 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1383.560267] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 24s! [kworker/1:2:5643]
Feb 10 16:39:30 tiago-Inspiron-7580 kernel: [ 1383.560268] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac bnep uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl videobuf2_memops btbcm btintel videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common bluetooth videodev mc ecdh_generic ecc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nls_iso8859_1 x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp nvidia_uvm(OE) kvm_intel kvm joydev nvidia_drm(POE) irqbypass nvidia_modeset(POE) sof_pci_dev snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda iwlmvm snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp mac80211 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core libarc4 snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine nvidia(POE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq crc32_pclmul snd_seq_device mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_timer i915 ghash_clmulni_intel dell_laptop iwlwifi aesni_intel ledtrig_audio
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Comment: Thanks, @heynnema. I've added the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: In `terminal` do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and then `dkms status` and then `reboot` and retest. We can always undo this later if it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @heynnema. I installed `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and rebooted the computer. The output of `dkms status` is now: `backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)`. I'm not sure this output is normal, but wifi is still working. I guess I should use the system a little more and see if the crashes stop.

Comment: Strange install. We may have to remove it later, if the crashes don't stop. Keep me posted.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: No crashes so far! :)

Comment: Curious. Show me the output of `ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`

Comment: Output added in Edit 3.

Comment: Remove the backport driver. Either `sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/7906 -k 5.3.0-26-generic` or `sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms`.

Comment: OK, I've just done that. I'll test for a while and report back.

Comment: Remember to add "Edit 4" to your question. Do you know how to re-seat the wifi/bluetooth module on your motherboard?

Comment: "Edit 4" added to the question. I'm not sure how to reseat the wifi module. But it's working fine on Windows 10 (I have a dual-boot setup). I haven't had crashes in Ubuntu for the last few days, even after I removed `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. I'm not sure what changed. I've also upgraded to the latest kernel version (5.3.0-29-generic), so maybe that helped.

Comment: The idea of re-seating the wifi card came because of the "HW error, resetting before reading" message. Re-seating means to open the laptop (if it's out of warranty), removing the one screw that secures the wifi/bluetooth module, wiggling the card in its slot, put back the screw, assure that the antenna wires are secure, and retest. But try the newer kernel and see if the problem reoccurs first.

Comment: Understood! I'll try that if the crashes resume. But I don't think it's a hardware issue because I never had Wifi problems on Windows. Thanks a lot for the help, @heynnema.

Comment: I've just has the crash twice. Log included above.

Comment: Because it works on Windows really doesn't say whether it'll work on Ubuntu. Completely different. You may have to do the wireless/bluetooth card re-seat that we discussed before. If you're not technical, or feel uncomfortable opening your laptop. get a technician to do it for you.

Comment: OK, I'll try to reseat the module as indicated. I've found a very similar report in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848921. The last comment isolated the issue better than I did... "The error occurs after booting Windows and then booting Linux afterwards. The error is quickly reproducible using speedtest.net or transferring a larger file of any kind. The ONLY solution to the problem in my case is: Shutting the system down and removing the power adapter. Then boot Linux and the error is gone."

Comment: I've been having the same issue for a while and the backport-iwlwifi changes haven't made a difference but like the previoust post says, I have also noticed that this only happens when rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how OP finally solved it but I'm having this exact same problem. Seems to happen for a pretty specific combination of hw/sw. I have: Ubuntu 19.10 installed from scratch last week (previously had upgraded from 19.04 and so forth and maybe that's why i'm having this problem just now), with kernel 5.3.0-46-generic, Intel 9260 Wi-Fi chip in a Dell XPS 9570. Problem seems to appear if i've booted Windows before Ubuntu.

I read through the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848921 which seems spot-on for this problem.

**Short-term** solution for me is the ridiculous (but working) one mentioned in the last comment: **if booting after Windows, turn off the machine, disconnect power adapter and then turn on Ubuntu.**

**Long-term** solution for me will be to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) as it comes out in a couple of weeks and [seems to fix this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848921/comments/45) (somewhere around **kernel 5.4.16**).

If this is not a possibility for the reader (though in this case you should already be avoiding non-LTS releases when running Ubuntu), you may try the other solutions mentioned in the bug discussion, such as:

- Make sure Windows has Fast Boot disabled
- Manually install a different firmware for iwlwifi: [download](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) the "-34" (`iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.XXXXX.X.tgz`), "manually copy the contained firmware to /lib/firmware, remove all other versions and make a link to iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-46.ucode that the kernel expects to load." (see [bug description](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848921))
- Try configuring options in `/etc/modprobe.d/wifi.conf` as mentioned [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1848921/comments/38)
- Try a different network chip (other than 9260)
- Uprade or downgrade to a different kernel version (there are other AskUbuntu answers for this). You may already have a different one installed, in which case you can try booting to it and see if the problem persists

Comment: Hello, maybe you could point to what you call "the other solutions" since it's not obvious in this long bug discussion.

Comment: Definitely, you're right. I'll add it in a bit.

Comment: For now, I've been doing what you described as the short-term solution. I'll upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 once the final version gets released. Let's hope that fixes the issue for good. I'll accept your answer because it provides a nice summary for those having the same issue.