# iwlwifi crashes often, sometimes taking the whole computer down with it

Tags: networking, kernel, iwlwifi

I have a [Dell G7 7590](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/dell-g7-15-gaming-laptop/spd/g-series-15-7590-laptop) laptop.
I am running:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

and the kernel:

`5.8.0-050800rc7-generic #202007262231 SMP Sun Jul 26 22:33:51 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

About two times a day my WiFi crashes, and once to twice a day my laptop freezes (sometimes it just hangs, sometimes a full reboot is required).

This is almost always accompanied by a lot of `iwlwifi` output in syslog (I assume becaue it is crashing).

I see [one similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205996/iwlwifi-causing-system-hangs-on-ubuntu-19-10).  I am using the `rc` kernel because I was having the same issue with the generic kernel and I needed to test new heat management.

Given that I have the latest hardware, OS and kernel version, can anybody help me find an answer to this extremely furstrating issue?

I part of the lengthy `syslog` output is pasted at the end of this post. I think the issue happened around 16:24.
The full log is [here](https://pastebin.com/azxXXTUn)

Other requested output is:

```
dmidecode -s bios-version 
1.13.2
```

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.2Gi       9.9Gi       158Mi       2.3Gi        11Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
ls -al /var/crash
total 544
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie   4096 Aug 18 19:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root       4096 Jul 15 16:35 ..
-rw-------  1 root whoopsie 248585 Aug 18 19:52 backport-iwlwifi-dkms.0.crash
-rw-------  1 root whoopsie 297497 Aug 16 17:01 virtualbox-dkms.0.crash
```

```
dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 450.57, 5.8.1, x86_64: installed
```

```
Aug 17 16:23:59 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.54' (uid=1000 pid=2588 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")
Aug 17 16:23:59 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.54' (uid=1000 pid=2588 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell ")
Aug 17 16:23:59 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Aug 17 16:23:59 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Aug 17 16:24:03 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 17 16:24:03 WORKCOM9001 update-manager.desktop[35656]: WARNING:root:can not import unity GI Namespace Unity not available
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' requested by ':1.405' (uid=1000 pid=35656 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager ") (using servicehelper)
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:04 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon: INFO: UpdateCache() was called
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]:   from gi.repository import PackageKitGlib as pk
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:04 AptDaemon [INFO]: UpdateCache() was called
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:04 AptDaemon.Trans [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:04 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:04 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:04 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:05 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Updating cache
Aug 17 16:24:05 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:05 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Updating cache
Aug 17 16:24:05 WORKCOM9001 snapd[1169]: 2020/08/17 16:24:05 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
Aug 17 16:24:07 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.408' (uid=0 pid=36402 comm="/usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedeskto")
Aug 17 16:24:07 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Aug 17 16:24:07 WORKCOM9001 PackageKit: daemon start
Aug 17 16:24:07 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Aug 17 16:24:07 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Aug 17 16:24:08 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' requested by ':1.410' (uid=1000 pid=36468 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk ") (using servicehelper)
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[36482]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[36482]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1134]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties'
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:09 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:11 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:11 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:24:11 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/3417ba8aa5194623a921b02f20e29e73
Aug 17 16:24:13 WORKCOM9001 update-manager.desktop[35656]: WARNING:root:Error loading .desktop file /usr/share/applications/evolution-calendar.desktop: constructor returned NULL
Aug 17 16:24:32 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:32 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:52 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:52 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:24:59 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:635a:78da:8878:b261 on wlp61s0.
Aug 17 16:24:59 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:635a:78da:8878:b261.
Aug 17 16:24:59 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:6828:c46f:75ce:a5ab.
Aug 17 16:24:59 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: A network interface address has gone down.
Aug 17 16:24:59 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: IP addresses from active interfaces: wlp61s0: 192.168.1.67, 2600:1700:5AB1:2010:6828:C46F:75CE:A5AB, FE80:0:0:0:C627:C182:E2A2:CA26
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Withdrawing address record for 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:6828:c46f:75ce:a5ab on wlp61s0.
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:6828:c46f:75ce:a5ab.
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address fe80::c627:c182:e2a2:ca26.
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Registering new address record for fe80::c627:c182:e2a2:ca26 on wlp61s0.*.
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: A network interface address has gone down.
Aug 17 16:25:00 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: IP addresses from active interfaces: wlp61s0: 192.168.1.67, FE80:0:0:0:C627:C182:E2A2:CA26
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 The HTTPS probe to 143.215.4.19 resulted in a redirect.
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: getProfilePath File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 576 Invoked Function: getpwnam Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: InitNSS File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 400 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::getProfilePath Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: CNSSCertStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertStore.cpp Line: 76 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::InitNSS Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: addNSSStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 1874 Invoked Function: CNSSCertStore::CNSSCertStore Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: OpenStores File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 449 Invoked Function: CCollectiveCertStore::addNSSStore Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1697 Invoked Function: CCertHelper::VerifyServerCertificate Return Code: -31391703 (0xFE210029) Description: CERTIFICATE_ERROR_VERIFY_SERVERCERT_FAILED_ASKUSER:Server certificate verification failed, and the error was an askuser error server name: ipsec7.vpn.gatech.edu
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Server certificate validation failed with the following errors:  #011Certificate is from an untrusted source.
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: TestAccessToSG File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1380 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::analyzeHttpResponse Return Code: -28901361 (0xFE47000F) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_CERT_VERIFICATION_FAILED:The server cert verification performed after the HTTPS probe has failed
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 The HTTP probe to 143.215.4.19 resulted in a redirect.
Aug 17 16:25:05 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1840 SG (143.215.4.19) contacted
Aug 17 16:25:11 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:25:11 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:25:18 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: gnome-launched-software-properties-gtk.desktop-36468.scope: Succeeded.
Aug 17 16:25:32 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:25:32 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:25:50 WORKCOM9001 gnome-shell[3160]: [3192:3197:0817/162550.721028:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
Aug 17 16:25:53 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:26:13 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: message repeated 3 times: [ RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network]
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon: INFO: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('gnome-shell'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-common'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-prefs'), dbus.String('im-config'), dbus.String('libegl-dev'), dbus.String('libegl1'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-2'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-tod1'), dbus.String('libgl-dev'), dbus.String('libgl1'), dbus.String('libgl1:i386'), dbus.String('libgles-dev'), dbus.String('libgles1'), dbus.String('libgles2'), dbus.String('libglvnd-dev'), dbus.String('libglvnd0'), dbus.String('libglvnd0:i386'), dbus.String('libglx-dev'), dbus.String('libglx0'), dbus.String('libglx0:i386'), dbus.String('libopengl-dev'), dbus.String('libopengl0'), dbus.String('python3-distupgrade'), dbus.String('sudo'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk'), dbus.String('unattended-upgrades')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:16 AptDaemon [INFO]: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('gnome-shell'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-common'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-prefs'), dbus.String('im-config'), dbus.String('libegl-dev'), dbus.String('libegl1'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-2'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-tod1'), dbus.String('libgl-dev'), dbus.String('libgl1'), dbus.String('libgl1:i386'), dbus.String('libgles-dev'), dbus.String('libgles1'), dbus.String('libgles2'), dbus.String('libglvnd-dev'), dbus.String('libglvnd0'), dbus.String('libglvnd0:i386'), dbus.String('libglx-dev'), dbus.String('libglx0'), dbus.String('libglx0:i386'), dbus.String('libopengl-dev'), dbus.String('libopengl0'), dbus.String('python3-distupgrade'), dbus.String('sudo'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk'), dbus.String('unattended-upgrades')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:16 AptDaemon.Trans [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:16 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Committing packages: dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('gnome-shell'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-common'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-prefs'), dbus.String('im-config'), dbus.String('libegl-dev'), dbus.String('libegl1'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-2'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-tod1'), dbus.String('libgl-dev'), dbus.String('libgl1'), dbus.String('libgl1:i386'), dbus.String('libgles-dev'), dbus.String('libgles1'), dbus.String('libgles2'), dbus.String('libglvnd-dev'), dbus.String('libglvnd0'), dbus.String('libglvnd0:i386'), dbus.String('libglx-dev'), dbus.String('libglx0'), dbus.String('libglx0:i386'), dbus.String('libopengl-dev'), dbus.String('libopengl0'), dbus.String('python3-distupgrade'), dbus.String('sudo'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk'), dbus.String('unattended-upgrades')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:16 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Committing packages: dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([dbus.String('gnome-shell'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-common'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons'), dbus.String('gnome-shell-extension-prefs'), dbus.String('im-config'), dbus.String('libegl-dev'), dbus.String('libegl1'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-2'), dbus.String('libfprint-2-tod1'), dbus.String('libgl-dev'), dbus.String('libgl1'), dbus.String('libgl1:i386'), dbus.String('libgles-dev'), dbus.String('libgles1'), dbus.String('libgles2'), dbus.String('libglvnd-dev'), dbus.String('libglvnd0'), dbus.String('libglvnd0:i386'), dbus.String('libglx-dev'), dbus.String('libglx0'), dbus.String('libglx0:i386'), dbus.String('libopengl-dev'), dbus.String('libopengl0'), dbus.String('python3-distupgrade'), dbus.String('sudo'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-core'), dbus.String('ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk'), dbus.String('unattended-upgrades')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:16 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:16 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/e6eb6489d46e4805b793644e96c5a79c
Aug 17 16:26:21 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Started debconf communication service.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address fe80::c627:c182:e2a2:ca26.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp61s0.IPv6 with address 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:635a:78da:8878:b261.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Registering new address record for 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:635a:78da:8878:b261 on wlp61s0.*.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c627:c182:e2a2:ca26 on wlp61s0.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: A new network interface address has been detected.
Aug 17 16:26:22 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: IP addresses from active interfaces: wlp61s0: 192.168.1.67, 2600:1700:5AB1:2010:635A:78DA:8878:B261, 2600:1700:5AB1:2010:8150:4913:92C0:31B8, FE80:0:0:0:C627:C182:E2A2:CA26
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 avahi-daemon[1128]: Registering new address record for 2600:1700:5ab1:2010:8150:4913:92c0:31b8 on wlp61s0.*.
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=123 pid=1490 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs ")
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=2225 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs ")
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Aug 17 16:26:24 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=123 pid=1490 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs ")
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 tracker-extract[37888]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 tracker-extract[37888]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[1499]: [session uid=123 pid=1499] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Reloaded configuration
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=2225 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs ")
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 tracker-extract[38031]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 tracker-extract[38031]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 dbus-daemon[2232]: [session uid=1000 pid=2232] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Aug 17 16:26:25 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/vpnagentd.service:10: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/vpnagentd.pid → /run/vpnagentd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded.
Aug 17 16:26:26 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: Starting Notification regarding a new release of Ubuntu...
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: Starting Notification regarding a new release of Ubuntu...
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 50-motd-news[38708]:  * Are you ready for Kubernetes 1.19? It's nearly here! Try RC3 with
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 50-motd-news[38708]:    sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.19/candidate --classic
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 50-motd-news[38708]:    https://microk8s.io/ has docs and details.
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Aug 17 16:26:27 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 The HTTPS probe to 143.215.4.19 resulted in a redirect.
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: getProfilePath File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 576 Invoked Function: getpwnam Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: InitNSS File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertUtils.cpp Line: 400 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::getProfilePath Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: CNSSCertStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/NSSCertStore.cpp Line: 76 Invoked Function: CNSSCertUtils::InitNSS Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: addNSSStore File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 1874 Invoked Function: CNSSCertStore::CNSSCertStore Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: OpenStores File: ../../vpn/CommonCrypt/Certificates/CollectiveCertStore.cpp Line: 449 Invoked Function: CCollectiveCertStore::addNSSStore Return Code: -31457275 (0xFE200005) Description: CERTSTORE_ERROR_NULL_POINTER
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1697 Invoked Function: CCertHelper::VerifyServerCertificate Return Code: -31391703 (0xFE210029) Description: CERTIFICATE_ERROR_VERIFY_SERVERCERT_FAILED_ASKUSER:Server certificate verification failed, and the error was an askuser error server name: ipsec7.vpn.gatech.edu
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Server certificate validation failed with the following errors:  #011Certificate is from an untrusted source.
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: TestAccessToSG File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1380 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::analyzeHttpResponse Return Code: -28901361 (0xFE47000F) Description: NETENVIRONMENT_ERROR_CERT_VERIFICATION_FAILED:The server cert verification performed after the HTTPS probe has failed
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1524 The HTTP probe to 143.215.4.19 resulted in a redirect.
Aug 17 16:26:28 WORKCOM9001 acvpnagent[1204]: Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1840 SG (143.215.4.19) contacted
Aug 17 16:26:30 WORKCOM9001 AptDaemon.Worker: CRITICAL: virtualbox-dkms: installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Aug 17 16:26:30 WORKCOM9001 org.debian.apt[35669]: 16:26:30 AptDaemon.Worker [CRITICAL]: virtualbox-dkms: installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Aug 17 16:26:34 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:26:34 WORKCOM9001 wpa_supplicant[1178]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
Aug 17 16:26:35 WORKCOM9001 systemd[2214]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 systemd[1433]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828693] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828882] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828883] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828884] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828885] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x0000104B | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
Aug 17 16:26:36 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [21266.828886] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: 0x0000A2F0 | trm_hw_status0
```

Comment: You shouldn't be running with the 5.8.0-050800rc7-generic kernel. `rc7` indicates `release candidate 7`, and should only be installed by developers who wish to test pre-release software. Revert to the stock 20.04.1 kernel. If you continue to have problems with iwlwifi, you may need a backport driver.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: Microcode software error detected for firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode. This file is in /lib/firmware. You may need a newer version, or back down to a prior version.

Comment: Microcode -46 is the newest, as per https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/

Comment: BIOS should be version 1.13.2, dated June 10, 2020

Comment: @heynnema - I am using the rc to test pre-release software and was having the same issue before.I  updated my BIOS and updated the question with the output you requested. Thanks for any input you have.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Dell G7 7590

Your BIOS is current at 1.13.2.

**kernel**

re: 5.8.0-050800rc7-generic

`rc7` indicates `release candidate 7`, and should only be installed by developers who wish to test pre-release software.

Try this instead:

[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.1/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.1/)

<strike>**iwlwifi**</strike>

Let's try the backport iwlwifi driver.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dkms backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

`reboot`

Comment: Trying to install the 5.8.1 kernel.  Currently having other issues:

```Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1139: vmlinux] Error 1```

Will update when finished.

Comment: @Startec I should just be a matter of installing four .deb files, no? Where does the makefile come info play? CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF is in /boot/config*.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  There was no documentation (not even a basic README) on that site you linked to so I followed these (mostly out of date) directions.  It broke my display system so I had to update and swap display managers a few times.

Comment: ``ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.1 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.1 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package backport-iwlwifi-dkms (--configure):
 installed backport-iwlwifi-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 backport-iwlwifi-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Currently trying to get the backported driver you linked to (don't I want the latest driver?)
Boy, is Linux worth it? (Starting to think *no* more every day).

Comment: @Startec Let's backup a bit. To install 5.8.1 you just installed 4 .deb files, yes? Did you run on 5.8.1 at all to see if iwlwifi crashed it again? Then it looks like you tried to install the backport driver, but it errored, due to the 5.8.1 being not supported. The backport driver would probably install fine on 5.4.x kernel... so if we have to go back, we can try that again to see if it fixes your problem... continued...

Comment: @Startec Linux startup can be troublesome, but for most, it's a breeze. Specialty hardware, or newest hardware, can sometimes make beginnings difficult, but after that, Linux is a hell of a lot better than Windows. So hang in there. If 5.8.1 didn't solve the iwlwifi problem, go back to 5.4.x, uninstall 5.8.1, install the backport driver, and see what happens.

Comment: I am trying to agree with you on Linux being better than Windows but I will say, I am losing faith.  However, I have been enduring 3 months of 2x a day freezing and crashes on this laptop so, I am trying to be in it for the long haul.  I don't think it's reasonable that a normal user should have to do this amount of work to get their system working. Basic things like "fractional GUI scaling" don't work either at least with nvidia. It's annoying. Anyway, I am at `5.8.1` now and the normal `iwlwifi` (which I don't know what that even is). No crashes in three hours. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: @Startec Good! Yes, after enduring this problem for 3 months, I'd question it all too. Keep me posted.

Comment: It started out with the same laptop overheating (i.e. https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/issues/241) one of your other posts kind of pointed me in the right direction although it seems like the kernel update helped more, so thanks for this help and that help.

Comment: @Startec Let me know in a day or so how it's running.

Comment: it does seem to be running a lot better. So far no crashing.  I also notice that most of the errors (all related to `ilwifi` that used to show up on startup / waking from sleep are gone).  Now only these errors: https://i.ibb.co/KGnxjwk/Screenshot-from-2020-08-19-19-22-49.png

Will let you know if there are no crashes for a full 24 hours.

Comment: Darn! After almost a full day of working it crashed again. Crash output is here if you can help: https://pastebin.com/egZJhhC3

I am also interested in why I would want to backport a driver when I just got the newest version of the kernel.  Wouldn't a newer driver be better?

Comment: You're on kernel 5.8.1, yes? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Go to /lib/firmware and temporarily rename 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode to 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.HOLD. Then reboot and try wifi. If wifi doesn't work at all, rename it back and reboot. Report back.

Comment: Updated with the crash output. I do get: ```/lib/firmware ()$ mv 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.HOLD
mv: cannot stat '9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode': No such file or directory 
```
when trying to move that file.

Comment: @Startec Oops. The correct filename is iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode. You'll have to do `sudo mv`. What should happen then is it should pick up the next newest available -43.ucode, and we'll see if that works.

Comment: Okay I did that - my wifi still works. I'll update you in two days about crashes or anything weird.

Comment: Still getting crashes, freezes system, although it self-recovered without a restart the last time.  Many errors in syslog, including: `Aug 22 18:39:41 WORKCOM9001 kernel: [ 5245.965883] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2` but like, hundreds of others :(

Comment: @Startec OK. Rename the .HOLD firmware back to .ucode. Install the backport iwlwifi driver. Report back.

Comment: I renamed the .HOLD firmware.  `sudo apt-get install dkms backport-iwlwifi-dkms` gives me:
```
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.1-5ubuntu1).
backport-iwlwifi-dkms is already the newest version (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.1).
```

Comment: @Startec Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Comment: updated. Thanks for sticking with this!

Comment: Installing backports to the latest kernel is a stupid idea.

Comment: @Startec It looks like `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` never fully got installed. Do `sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. After that, I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @Pilot6 You're right. See my previous comment to OP. Maybe you have some ideas on how to solve this problem, as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: We need to test it on the 5.4 Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: @Startec You originally had this problem when running on the stock Ubuntu 20.04.1 kernel, correct? That's what originally got you to try the newer kernel, correct?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't have the "backport driver" whatever that is?

Comment: @Startec It's moot, as the backport driver never really got installed. So you can just uninstall it as per my previous comment from -12 hours ago. Hopefully "@pilot6" can help more.

Comment: @Pilot6 Do you have time to help? I'm out of ideas.