# WiFi stuck on authentication loop Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, broadcom, realtek

After entering the password for the WiFi it keep asking for authentication over and over again,
in-spit what password is passed wrong or right.

description: Wireless interface

> ```
>            product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
>            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>            physical id: 0
>            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
>            logical name: wlp4s0
>            version: 00
>            serial: 80:91:33:f4:ff:83
>            width: 64 bits
>            clock: 33MHz
>            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-7629-generic >firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
>           resources: irq:70 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff.
> ```

-after reinstalling the driver from

> https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

-still stuck in the same loop,reinstalled network-manger still no hope.

Comment: Has the same problem on 19.10 and just removed the driver, that was incompatible and unnecessary with kernels V5. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203808/network-password-rejected-after-installing-backport-iwlwifi-dkms) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205996/iwlwifi-causing-system-hangs-on-ubuntu-19-10).

Comment: @xenoid before i installed the driver mentioned above the same issue was still present